# How can l import an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I created a file

```
#name file ask.py
def ask_name():
    user = input("What is your name?: ")
```

and i imported it

```
import ask
ask.ask_name()
print(user)
```

but python tells me that "user" is not defined.

Comment: so many ways this can be done...but you'll probably want to add `return user` in `ask.py` module, then it would be possible to define "user" by changing that line to `user = ask.ask_name()` then your print statement will work.

Answer (score 3):

It's not: **user** is a variable internal to **ask_name**, not an attribute of **ask**.  Try this:

```
#name file ask.py
def ask_name():
    user = input("What is your name?: ")
    return user

# Main file
import ask
local_input = ask.ask_name()
print(local_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `user` variable "lives" only inside the 'ask_name` function (read [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) to learn more about variable scope), so it's undefined within the main script.
you can have the function return the user's input, and print that returned value.

```
#name file ask.py
def ask_name():
    return input("What is your name?: ")

# Main file
import ask
print(ask.ask_name())
```

Comment: You can't actually `return = input()`. It should be `return input("What is your name?: ")`